Understanding local inertial frames
I am trying to understand what it means exactly that for every point in a spacetime which is a 4D Lorentzian manifold, spacetime is locally inertial.
As an example, consider a spacetime described by Rindler metric
$$ds^2=-(ax)^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2.$$
For an observer standing on a fixed spatial coordinate $(x,y,z)=(\frac1a,0,0)$ (default Rindler observer), this metric becomes $ds^2=-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ which is precisely the flat spacetime metric, right? I am confused how this is interpreted. An observer inside Rindler spacetime feels fictitious forces, so his reference frame is obviously not inertial but this contradicts with the fact that this reference frame can be described by the flat spacetime metric?
What about an observer on a fixed spatial coordinate $(x,y,z)=(\frac2a,0,0)$ in Rindler spacetime described by the same metric above? Does this observer also have their own locally inertial frame that can be described by the flat spacetime metric?

"An observer inside Rindler spacetime feels fictitious forces, so his reference frame is obviously not inertial but this contradicts with the fact that this reference frame can be described by the flat spacetime metric?" - You can describe metrics that, at a given point, are Minkowski but aren't at other points and thus produce nonzero Christoffel symbols and thus nonzero fictitious forces.

@controlgroup So all non-inertial observers are inertial at their own point?

My point was that a spacetime being/appearing flat at a single point does not immediately imply the absence of fictitious forces.

“spacetime is locally inertial’ - The property of being “inertial” applies to observes or frames, not to spacetimes. Any spacetime contains inertial and non-inertial frames sharing the same event. Perhaps what you mean is that every spacetime event is on some timelike geodesic.

@safesphere Oh, I meant to write "spacetime is locally flat." To be more precise, metric at that point looks like the Minkowski metric. I had a brainfart.

Then you should edit the question to correct the typo.
